# JS: Sending POST to server, getting no response

Tags: javascript, postman

I am sending a Postman `POST` to a LDAP Server. When I use the `GET` response for one function it works; however, when I use the `POST` for another function that involves `client.binding.` I get no response, "Could not get any response" after 1 minute of waiting. I am using http, with no proxy.

---

GET that works:

```
   IAMserver.get('/account/list', function(req,res){
        //list accounts for a compangy. seraches everyhting under provided compagny node.
        let enterprise = req.jwtPayload.enterprise || "Enterprise";
        var opts = {
            //filter: 'cn='+base,
            filter: '(objectclass=person)',
            scope: 'sub'
        };
            console.log(result);
            console.log('status: ' + result.status);
            respondWithJSON(200, 0, "Success", res, entries);
```

---

POST that doesn't work:

```
IAMserver.post('/account/modify', function(req,res){
    if(req.jwtPayload.entityData == null || req.jwtPayload.entityData == {}){
        respondWithJSON(400, 400, "No entity data provided or data was not JSON encoded.", res);
        return;
    }
    //Check if exists already.
    aSearch(req.jwtPayload.cn).then(
    //exists
    function(result){
        //Bind to admin account.
        client.bind(adminCred, adminPass, function(err){
            if(err){
                respondWithJSON(500,500, err.message, res);
                return;
            }
        });
        //define modifications
        let changes = new ldap.Change({
            operation: 'replace',
            modification: req.jwtPayload.entityData
        });
        //try to modify.
        client.modify('cn='+req.jwtPayload.cn+',ou=Enterprise,dc=abc,dc=com', changes, function(err){
            if(err){
                respondWithJSON(500, 500, err.message, res);
                return;
            }
            respondWithJSON(200, 0, "Changes executed correctly.", res);
        });
    },
    //Doesn't exist, can't modify.
    function(result){
        respondWithJSON(200,1, "Failure. "+result.message, res);
    });
});
```

Comment: But I am seeing that both your request is `.post`

Comment: Yes that is correct. I just wanted to emphasize the difference in functionality for the problem. But code wise, I should switch it.

Comment: Did you tried to handle the error case of "post" request? This could give you some more information if something is went wrong.